# Getting summarizing values in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem when I try to get a combined remaining balance between two fields from two tables,

the requirement: Calculate the combined remaining balance of all outlets based only on the income_o and outcome_o tables.

my query is:

```
select (RE.inc-RE.out) AS  dif
FROM(
SELECT SUM(RESULTADO.inc) inc, SUM(RESULTADO.out) out
    FROM
    (
        SELECT point, date, null as out, inc
        FROM Income_o
        UNION ALL
        SELECT point, date, out, null as inc
        FROM Outcome_o
    ) RESULTADO
) RE
```

and my result is:

```
28985.9600
```

and the correct result is:

```
28985.9600
```

but when I run my query the program  tell me than my query is incorrect, but however my result it's right

link of database schema: http://img1.imagilive.com/affiche/0315/Snap_09-03-2015_at_144932.jpg.htm

Comment: Do you get an error if you run `SELECT (SELECT SUM(inc) FROM Income_o) - (SELECT SUM(out) FROM  Outcome_o) AS dif ;`

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: when I executed that query the error message is : Your query failed on third checking database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try it this way.

```
SELECT SUM(t.IncOut) AS 'dif'
FROM (
    SELECT inc AS 'IncOut'
    FROM Income_o
    UNION ALL
    SELECT out * -1
    from Outcome_o
) t
```

Comment: thank so much for your help. That query is the correct. thanks, thanks, thanks......